# i just want to redirect to new form of different website onclick event of button i tried of three methods

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Navigating from one form to other
please help me on this..

i just want to redirect to new form of different website on Button click event. i tried of three methods

1. `btnLogin.PostBackUrl = URL;` - which is working on clicking two time of button.
2. `Response.Redirect(URL);` - which is giving Thread Abort Exception and navigating to same page.
3. `Response.Redirect(URL,false);` - Not giving any Exception but navigating to same page.

Comment: You second method is working perfectly fine for me can you post  the relevant code.

Comment: Take a look on this -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/891909

Comment: What is the value of  the `URL` string you are trying to redirect to? Does it include the full URI, including protocol?

Comment: My URL is some thing like this--- string URL = "http://" + domain + "siteName" + app_serverstr + "menu.aspx"; and as well i need to maintain the hidden fields that are created in the source page to destination page