# Difference between PostbackURL and response.redirect on buttonclick

Tags: asp.net

Whats the exact difference between `PostbackURL` property of a button and redirecting to the same page using `Response.Redirect()` to the same URL on Button Click event in Code behind and which one to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostBackUrl Vs Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891441/postbackurl-vs-response-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Post back url is basically same as server. Transfer. It will maintain view state of your page and from post back page you will get your page object and all value but it will work for only url of same server.

Repose. Redirect means transfer your browser execution to point this page. Means you can write response. Redirect (“www.google.com”)   so when it will firer browser go to  Google website. url not required on same server

[More detail check](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/69851/postbackurl-vs.-response.redirect)

Comment: First, it won't maintain any view state and second, the link you provided have numorous answers and OP won't be able to know where to look. May be there are wrong answers like yours. Please delete or modify your answer with correct knowledge.